# Unity ARFoundation Gradle build fails - last-build.bin access denied

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, arcore

I am trying to build in Unity its ARFoundations AR example for ARCore (https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples) using Unity's Gradle build option but fails as shown below.

- What went wrong:
  Could not update C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\4.0.1\file-changes\last-build.bin

  > C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\4.0.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

I don't know much android studio, can you please give me guidance what this may relate to?

Thanks a bunch for your help , Sergio

My setup:

- Unity 2018.1.6. ARFoundation, AR Core XR Plugin, ARKit XR Plugins
  installed via package manager
- Build setup: ARFoundation scene example, Building on Gradle, min API
  7.0 max highest installed, Target Architecture ARMv7, multithreaded rendering off
- jdk1.8.0_172, Android sdk 3.1.3
- Fails the same with Development build toggled on and off

Error:
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.1.6f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not update C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\4.0.1\file-changes\last-build.bin

  > C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\4.0.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 45s
]

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:182 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:89 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

Answer (score 1):

quick update in case this can be helpful to anyone who had a similar problem.

resolved it by simply selecting the properties of the gradle folder in c directory and settings its Attributes to not read-only and unhide files.

Cheers, Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Go C:\Users\user and remove from hidden .gradle folder by right click.
Also Go security and apply all permisions